# Activate custom Conda environment in Dockerfile

Tags: anaconda, dockerfile, conda

In my `Dockerfile`, I create one Conda environment and install all packages I need. At the end of `Dockerfile`, I would like to start one service when container is created.

The original `Dockerfile` is not Conda environment, the commands look like:

```docker
EXPOSE 8868

CMD ["/bin/bash","-c","hub install deploy/hubserving/ocr_system/ && hub serving start -m ocr_system"]
```

I would like to modify the commands like so:

```bash
activate myenv
hua install and hub servering start
```

**How do I activate the Conda environment in the container?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know where your `conda` is located (let's say `/opt/miniconda3/condabin/conda`), then you could directly use `conda run`. Something like:

```docker
CMD ['/opt/miniconda3/condabin/conda', 'run', '--no-capture-output',
     'hub', 'install', 'deploy/hubserving/ocr_system/', '"&&"', 
     'hub', 'serving', 'start', '-m=ocr_system']
```

The argument delimiting might need some adjusting, but that's the spirit of it.If this is a non-**base** env, then you may also need a `--name|-n` argument to the `conda run`.